# Flatten arrays in an object

Tags: javascript

I have an object as below:

```js
const USER_MAP = {
  PREMIUM: ['a', 'b'],
  RETAIL: ['c', 'd']
};
```

I would like to transform to below

```js
[
  { segment: 'PREMIUM', id: 'a' },
  { segment: 'PREMIUM', id: 'b' },
  { segment: 'RETAIL', id: 'c' },
  { segment: 'RETAIL', id: 'd' }
]
```

I came up with a solution as below

```js
const USER_MAP = {
  PREMIUM: ['a', 'b'],
  RETAIL: ['c', 'd']
};


const userList = Object.entries(USER_MAP).reduce((accumulator, currentValue) => {
   const userListByType = currentValue[1].map(id => ({ id, segment: currentValue[0]}))
  return [...accumulator, ...userListByType]
}, []);

console.log(userList);
```

It works but im wondering if there might be a better way to achieve above? In terms of readability as I'm nesting a `map` in a `reduce`, it seems to me that I might've complicated stuffs here

Comment: if your code works you might want to look at code review SE

Comment: This looks good, another way would be using flatmap `Object.entries(USER_MAP).flatMap(([segment,retail])=>retail.map(id=>({segment, id})))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could take [`Array#flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) with a mapping of nested objects with outer key.

```js
const
    USER_MAP = { PREMIUM: ['a', 'b'], RETAIL: ['c', 'd'] },
    result = Object
        .entries(USER_MAP)
        .flatMap(([segment, a]) => a.map(id => ({ segment, id })));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```